Calculating 2d shape points from discrete curvature
I have a set of curvatures that I've derived from discrete points of a closed 2d curve. If I have a starting point and starting orientation and the starting set of points were equidistantly spaced at distance l.
I naively tried to simply move along osculating circle by a chord of length l but this doesn't work where l >> r.
Anyone have any advice or a reference to an algorithm that can help reconstruct the 2d shape somehow? The algorithm I used to determine the discrete curvature to begin with is here: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11042-019-07792-x

If you have the points, you can try one of several curve reconstruction algorithms.
